# Custom Materialize CSS Style

Tags: css, frameworks, materialize, typography

Materialize use 'Roboto' as default typeface.
I'm not trying(as provided by documentation) to change the custom CSS like this:

```
html {
   font-family: GillSans, Calibri, Trebuchet, sans-serif;
}
```

What i'm looking for is to change the original style of h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6,  and p, a, elements for 'Poppins' font in different weights incluuding Extra-Bold, Bold and Medium with font-sizes of 75pt, 50pt, 30pt and, 25pt.

I have tried custom CSS for each element including:

```
 font-size: 30pt; 
 font-weight: 'Extra-Bold' !important;
```

I also have tried the html 'browser-default' class, and also tried:

```
*{
    font-family: initial;
}
```

The font is linked like this in the style.css sheet:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Poppins);
```

And, the stylesheets are imported too.

```
  <link href = ' css/materialize.min.css ' type = ' text/css ' rel = ' stylesheet ' media = ' screen,projection ' /> 
  <link href = ' css/styles.css ' type = ' text/css ' rel = ' stylesheet ' media = ' screen,projection ' />
```

I have done several tests including or not those things.

How can I Disable Specific Style Rules of Materialize and Personalize the CSS Typography Styles, directly with Materialize or a Custom CSS?

Comment: Is it typo or actual line in your code? `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css family=Poppins` should be `http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins`

Comment: Also, font-weights are numbers, 100 to 900, not strings; extra bold should be 800. And I'm not sure all those spaces in your attribute values are OK.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is with your import. There is a typo, you should use https instead, and you should specify the font-weights you need. 500 would be 'medium', 700 'bold' and 800 'extra-bold'

Furthermore, when specifying the font-weight in your selector, you don't use a string, but one of the predefined values or a numeric value.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-weight

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Poppins:500,700,800');

h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, a {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 800;
}
```